# Hadoop Path must not be null

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a external table. While trying to drop it i am getting this following error

```
Metaexception(message:java.lang.illegalArgumentException:hadoop path must not be null)(state=08s01,code=1)
```

I tried to change it to managed table with Alter command which went successful, but encountering the same problem while trying to drop.

Answer (score 0):

When the table is created inside a location which cannot be deleted/dropped by design. It throws out this error.

If a table is already created you could change it's location by making a folder inside that location and storing that table inside that.

Now when you try to drop it....it will work.